# Running systemd in docker container causes host crash

Tags: docker, systemd

I'm trying to create a systemd based docker container, but when I try running the built container my system crashes. I think running init in the container might be causing the conflict, and is somehow conflicting with systemd on my host.

When I try to run the docker container I am logged out of my account and briefly see what looks like my system going through a boot process. My host is running Arch Linux, with linux 4.20.7.

It is only when I attempt to "boot" the container by running systemd via `/sbin/init`, that the problem occurs.

```
docker run -it \
   --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw \
   --privileged 66304e3bc48
```

---

Dockerfile (adapted from [solita/ubuntu-systemd](https://hub.docker.com/r/solita/ubuntu-systemd/dockerfile)):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Don't start any optional services.
RUN find /etc/systemd/system \
    /lib/systemd/system \
    -path '*.wants/*' \
    -not -name '*journald*' \
    -not -name '*systemd-tmpfiles*' \
    -not -name '*systemd-user-sessions*' \
    -exec rm \{} \;

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes \
    python sudo bash ca-certificates dbus systemd && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
RUN systemctl mask dev-hugepages.mount sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount

STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3

# Workaround for docker/docker#27202, technique based on comments from docker/docker#9212
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec /sbin/init --log-target=journal 3>&1"]
```

I would expect the container to just boot up running systemd, and I'm not your what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Adding `--privileged` gives the container process this right, and systemd wants to manage a _lot_ of things.  Could you meet your end goal with a lighter-weight init process like supervisord, or better still, a single-process container without a dedicated init?

Comment: I would prefer to do that, the problem is I am using it for configuration management testing and so I want the container to match the host as close as possible. I end up needing to test that restarting services using `systemctl` works.

Comment: "Match the host as close as possible": a Docker container doesn't run many of the things that a typical full host system runs, including system daemons, remote login services, _etc._  If "match the host" is your goal a virtual machine will be a much more natural match.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that isn't really feasible. I'm hoping to test the roles during a CI run where only docker containers are available.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Ubuntu 19.04 and Docker nightly builds. Also had this problem with Ubuntu 18.04 and whatever the current docker release was. The host system isn't rebooting - X11 appears to be crashing or being terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the [paulfantom/ubuntu-molecule](https://hub.docker.com/r/paulfantom/ubuntu-molecule) Docker image.

Currently it looks like they're just installing systemd, setting some environment variables, and using the systemd binary directly as the entry point. It seems to work without the issues I mentioned in the original post.

[Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/paulfantom/ubuntu-molecule/dockerfile)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV container docker
ENV LC_ALL C
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN sed -i 's/# deb/deb/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

# hadolint ignore=DL3008
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends systemd python sudo bash iproute2 net-tools \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# hadolint ignore=SC2010,SC2086
RUN cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/ \
    && ls | grep -v systemd-tmpfiles-setup | xargs rm -f $1

RUN rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* \
    /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* \
    /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* \
    /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/* \
    /lib/systemd/system/plymouth* \
    /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*

RUN systemctl set-default multi-user.target
ENV init /lib/systemd/systemd
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker do not want to include by default Systemd inside docker because it publish itself as an **application container** (which means one application per container). There is an other type of containers called **system containers**. the most known are OpenVZ , LXC/LXD and Systemd-nspawn. all those will run a full OS with systemd as if it were a virtual machine.

and using systemd inside docker is so dangerous when compared to running systemd inside LXD

there is even a new baby called Podman which is a clone of docker but it uses by default systemd inside when you install it or when you use an image which contain systemd already like those of ubuntu cloud images http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/server/bionic/release/

so my advice is to test LXD and systemd-nspawn ; and keep an eye on Podman it solves what docker do not want to solve; read this to understand https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/

---

references:

https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/rkt-vs-other-projects.html
https://podman.io/slides/2018_10_01_Replacing_Docker_With_Podman.pdf
https://containerjournal.com/features/system-containers-vs-application-containers-difference-matter

**Runtimes And the Curse of the Privileged Container**
https://brauner.github.io/2019/02/12/privileged-containers.html

Answer (score 1):

To "match the host as close as possible" was the original goal of the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script. You can test drive scripts in a container that may be run later on a virtual machine. It allows to do some systemctl commands without an active systemd daemon.

It can also serve as an init daemon if you wish to. A systemd-enabled operating system will feel quite similar inside a container with it.

Comment: I had tried this but couldn't get it working. I think I was just missing Python 3, since after trying again, and making sure it's installed, it's now working. I'll give it a shot and see if it does the job.

Comment: Ahh, I see - thanks for the feedack. I have put a hint on the Python requirement on the front page. ................... A few years back all the docker images had Python pre-installed just like the real operating systems but that has changed somewhen in the last year. By 2019 it is basically a general requirement to install python in a docker image when one wants to use python-based tools. Similary, Ansible wants to be clever so one needs to create the /run/systemd/system directory by now. Having that on the frontpage as well may be a good idea by now.